# Push Sidebar Nav Menu

Tags: css

I am trying to get a sidebar push navigation that looks like    [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push). I do actually have content in between my center element div. My html looks like:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
</a>
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Projects</a>
<a href="#">Hire Me</a>
</div>

<div id = "main">

<span style="font-size:50px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()" id="btnMenu">&#9776;</span>

<div class = "centerElement">

</div>
</div>
```

I believe its probably because my centerElement class that is not allowing its content to be pushed. If that is true my btnMenu will also have to be changed.

css code here:

```
 .centerElement {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
 margin: -300px 0 0 -300px;
}

#main {
transition: margin-right .5s;
padding: 16px;
}

#btnMenu {
position: absolute;
top: 72px;
right: 128px;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

javascript is

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
}
```

I also tried my first fiddle but for some reason my navbar doesn't even open in it.  Didn't really care to put the effort to find out why but if this helps here it [is](https://jsfiddle.net/L9a6so1w/).

Answer (score 0):

I got your fiddle working in a code pen, if I understand your question you want to push the content to the side when opening the side nav. I changed a few css properties to achieve this.

you have your `centerElement` which has `position: absolute;` this wont allow it to adjust to the side nav when it opens.

same with your `btnMenu` icon

I created a div around your `btnMenu` and added

```
.menuIcon {
  text-align: right;
}
```

which places it on the right side like you had it.
also I removed your `btnMenu` styles

I also changed your `.centerElement` class to

```
.centerElement {
  width: 45%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

this centers the content and adjusts when the nav opens.

You may have to play with some other margins and padding to get things to line up, but I think this is what your going for.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjORpO

Comment: Thank you, I can mess around with it now